# Sram thumb lever issue

Tags: shifter

Is there anyway I can fix this for it to function properly again, or am I gonna need a whole new shifter? The lever is cracked and broken at the collar where the hex bolt threads in so I'm guessing I'm screwed because it obviously won't shift now it just pops off the bottom of the trigger shifter

[image]

[image]

Comment: JB Weld?  SuperGlue?

Comment: I would probably try epoxy.  But it's unlikely any glue will hold.

Answer (score 2):

It's unfixable.

Depending on the model of shifter you may be able to get a replacement part, or find a used replacement shifter on Ebay.

Comment: It's Sram X01 Eagle so obviously not cheap for a replacement lever that's why I was curious on any possibility to fix but I think I got my answer thanks

Comment: @Iowamtb87 I'd try contacting Sram customer service and see if you can purchase a replacement part.